# feign.FeignException$NotFound: status 404 reading service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, feign

I am deploying 2 simple spring boot micro-services in my kubernetes cluster and I am trying to achieve service to service communication using feign and ribbon but getting the below exception (Both services are up and running)

```
feign.FeignException$NotFound: status 404 reading ServiceBClient#getInfo()
```

Comment: This seems there is an issue with your code. It is trying to call get function.